# Impossible Bootstrap Layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I am working on a programmatic method for laying out bootstrap grids. Is there a correct way to lay out a theme such as this?

```
  MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM 
  MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM 
  MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM 
  MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM 
  MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM 
                         MMMMMMM  
  MMMMMMM  MMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM   
  MMMMMMM  MMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM 
  MMMMMMM  MMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM 
  MMMMMMM  MMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM  
  MMMMMMM  MMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM  
  MMMMMMM  MMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM  
  MMMMMMM  MMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM  
  MMMMMMM  MMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM  
  MMMMMMM  MMMMMMMMMMMM  MMMMMMM  
  MMMMMMM        
  MMMMMMM MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM 
  MMMMMMM MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM 
  MMMMMMM MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM 
  MMMMMMM MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  
  MMMMMMM MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

Up to this point I have been able to solve the following layouts, however this one is a stumper.

```
1) e.g. row { column, column { row { column }, row { column } } }
 _____  _____
|     ||_____|
|_____||_____|

2) e.g. row { column { row { column }, row { column, column } } , column }
 ______  _____  
|______||     |
|__||__||_____|

3) e.g. row { column{ row { column }, row { column } } column { row { column }, row{ column }} }
 ______  ______
|______||      |
|      ||______|         
|______||______|

4) e.g. row { column, column, column } row{ column } 
 ____  ____  ____
|____||____||____|
|________________|

5) e.g. row { column { row { column } row { column } column, column, column }
 ____ ____  ____
|____|    ||    | 
|____|____||____|
```

Comment: no..........................

Comment: Not trying to be facetious and I apologize for any offensive resemblance this may have. I posted to see if any bootstrap wizard out there can show how this is possible using only columns and rows.

Comment: Do you want this layout to stay the same no matter what screen-size?

Comment: No, the responsive element to the layout can be flexible. I just want to get this layout built using rows and columns, no hacks like absolute positioning etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you have to fake one portion of the grid. In my example, you fake the bottom right portion, by actually splitting it into two sections, each within their own parent columns, but right next to each other. If the content within that split section can work this way, then it works, but if the content needs to flow a certain way, it may not. Enough talk - here's the example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 bg-danger" style="height:50px">Top-Left</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 bg-info" style="height:100px">Left</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 bg-success" style="height:50px">Middle</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 bg-danger" style="height:50px">Left half of bottom right</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 bg-warning" style="height:100px">Top-Right</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 bg-danger" style="height:50px">Right half of bottom right</div>
</div>
```

**DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/xVUJOEq45F#**

If you need the grids to react responsively, it gets much more complicated. But probably still possible, just not at top of mind right now.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap does not allow you to do what you are looking for,
as it is built on CSS "float" property which does not "fill" gaps in columns.

For this kind of "tiles" structure, I would suggest :

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

http://masonry.desandro.com/